# Change IP Address of subdomain to match main domain

Tags: whm

I have a VPS server with the main server url being XYZ.COM. That domain is on its own private IP address.  My mail server is sending from VPS.XYZ.COM but it appears to be on the shared IP address that all of the individual website accounts are on.  This is causing problems with email getting marked as spam.

Can I simply switch the subdomain of VPS.XYZ.COM to be on the same IP or will this mess things up?  I currently use the url VPS.XYZ.COM to log into the server WHM/cPanel as well. If I can put them both on the same IP how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign same dedicated IP Address to your sub domains on your server. You can refer following steps for it:

Log in to the server as the root user via SSH. 
Navigate to the /var/cpanel/userdata/username directory. 
Open the subdomain.example.com file with a text editor. 
Find IP: ip: X.X.X.X and Change the ip line to reflect the dedicated IP address to assign to the subdomain,

Now, you will need to rebuild apache and restart the services for it. Manually rebuild and restart Apache. To do this, run the following commands:

/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf 
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_apache

Now, update DNS records file for subdomain from WHM Panel:

Edit the subdomain's IP address in WHM's Edit DNS Zone interface (Home >> DNS Functions >> Edit DNS Zone).
Edit the subdomain's IP address with the WHM API 1 Functions - editzonerecord function call.

NOTE: To reserve the subdomain's dedicated IP address, Add the subdomains' dedicated IP address to the reserved IP list so that the system does not assign it other accounts or sites.

Perform this action in WHM's Show Edit Reserved IPs interface (Home >> IP Functions >> Show/Edit Reserved IPs).

It should not conflict with your VPS/WHM access for your domain/sub domain.